# Add a constraint to prevent simultanous charing and discharging of a battery

Tags: pyomo

I am trying to find the optimal dispatch for a battery across different markets for buying and selling energy. I ran into the problem, that the battery is simultansouly charging and discharging in the same market. How does my constraint look like to avoid simultaneous charging and discharging?

**Here is my example:**

```
def battery_optimisation(data: pd.DataFrame, technical_parameters=None, include_revenue=True, solver: str='glpk'):
    
    # Battery's technical specification
    MIN_BATTERY_CAPACITY = 0
    MAX_BATTERY_CAPACITY = 100
    MAX_RAW_POWER = 40
    INITIAL_CAPACITY = 0 
    EFFICIENCY = 1

    battery = ConcreteModel()

    solvername='glpk'
    solverpath_folder='C:\\glpk-4.65\\w64'
    solverpath_exe='C:\\glpk-4.65\\w64\\glpsol' 

    opt = SolverFactory(solver,executable=solverpath_exe)

    battery.Period = Set(initialize=list(data.period), ordered=True)
    
    battery.Price = Param(initialize=list(data.spot_hourly), within=Any)
    battery.intraday = Param(initialize=list(data.id_hourly), within=Any)
    battery.fcr_hourly = Param(initialize=list(data.fcr_hourly), within=Any)
    battery.afrr_up = Param(initialize=list(data.afrr_up_energy_hourly), within=Any)
    battery.afrr_down = Param(initialize=list(data.afrr_down_energy_hourly), within=Any)

    # battery variables
    battery.Capacity = Var(battery.Period, bounds=(MIN_BATTERY_CAPACITY, MAX_BATTERY_CAPACITY))
    battery.Charge_power = Var(battery.Period, bounds=(0, MAX_RAW_POWER))
    battery.Discharge_power = Var(battery.Period, bounds=(0, MAX_RAW_POWER))

    battery.charge_power_dah = Var(battery.Period, bounds=(0, MAX_RAW_POWER))
    battery.discharge_power_dah = Var(battery.Period, bounds=(0, MAX_RAW_POWER))

    battery.charge_power_intra = Var(battery.Period, bounds=(0, MAX_RAW_POWER))
    battery.discharge_power_intra = Var(battery.Period, bounds=(0, MAX_RAW_POWER))

    battery.charge_power_fcr = Var(battery.Period, bounds=(0, MAX_RAW_POWER))
    battery.discharge_power_fcr = Var(battery.Period, bounds=(0, MAX_RAW_POWER))

    battery.charge_power_afrr = Var(battery.Period, bounds=(0, MAX_RAW_POWER))
    battery.discharge_power_afrr = Var(battery.Period, bounds=(0, MAX_RAW_POWER))

    battery.power_balance =Var(battery.Period, doc='binary variable', within=Binary, initialize=0)
    battery.power_p = Var(battery.Period, doc='energy derivative with respect to time',  initialize=0)

    # Set constraints for the battery
    # Defining the battery objective (function to be maximise)

    def maximise_profit(battery):

        rev = sum(data.id_hourly[i] * (battery.discharge_power_intra[i] / 2 * EFFICIENCY) for i in battery.Period) + \
              sum(data.fcr_hourly[i] * (battery.discharge_power_fcr[i] / 2 * EFFICIENCY) for i in battery.Period) + \
              sum(data.afrr_up_energy_hourly[i] * (battery.discharge_power_afrr[i] / 2 * EFFICIENCY) for i in battery.Period) + \
              sum(data.spot_hourly[i] * (battery.discharge_power_dah[i] / 2 * EFFICIENCY) for i in battery.Period) 

        cost = sum(data.id_hourly[i] * (battery.charge_power_intra[i] / 2)  for i in battery.Period) + \
               sum(data.fcr_hourly[i] * (battery.charge_power_fcr[i] / 2)  for i in battery.Period) + \
               sum(data.afrr_down_energy_hourly[i] * (battery.charge_power_afrr[i] / 2)  for i in battery.Period) + \
               sum(data.spot_hourly[i] * (battery.charge_power_dah[i] / 2)  for i in battery.Period) 

        return rev - cost

    # CONSTRAINT - BATTERY CAN'T CHARGE OVER CAPACITY
    def over_charge(battery, i):

        battery_charge = battery.charge_power_intra[i] + \
                         battery.charge_power_fcr[i]  + \
                         battery.charge_power_afrr[i] + \
                         battery.charge_power_dah[i]   
        
        return battery_charge <= (MAX_BATTERY_CAPACITY - battery.Capacity[i]) * 2 / EFFICIENCY

    # CONSTRAINT - CAN DISCHARGE MORE THAN CAPITY
    def over_discharge(battery, i):
        
        battery_charge =  battery.discharge_power_intra[i] + \
                          battery.discharge_power_fcr[i] + \
                          battery.discharge_power_afrr[i] + \
                          battery.discharge_power_dah[i]  

        return battery_charge <= battery.Capacity[i] * 2


    # CONSTRAINT - BATTERY CAN'T DISCHARGE IF PRICES ARE NEGATIVE
    def negative_discharge_spot(battery, i):
        # if the spot price is not positive, suppress discharge
        if battery.Price.extract_values_sparse()[None][i] <= 0:
            return battery.Discharge_power[i] == 0

        # otherwise skip the current constraint    
        return Constraint.Skip

    # CONSTRAINT - CAPACITY RULE
    def capacity_constraint(battery, i):
        # Assigning battery's starting capacity at the beginning
        if i == battery.Period.first():
            return battery.Capacity[i] == INITIAL_CAPACITY
        # if not update the capacity normally    

        battery_capacity = (battery.Capacity[i-1] \
                        + ((battery.charge_power_intra[i-1] / 2 * EFFICIENCY) \
                        + (battery.charge_power_fcr[i-1] / 2 * EFFICIENCY) \
                        + (battery.charge_power_afrr[i-1] / 2 * EFFICIENCY) \
                        + (battery.charge_power_dah[i-1] / 2 * EFFICIENCY)) \
                        - ((battery.discharge_power_intra[i-1] / 2) \
                        + (battery.discharge_power_fcr[i-1] / 2) \
                        + (battery.discharge_power_afrr[i-1] / 2) \
                        + (battery.discharge_power_dah[i-1] / 2)))

        return battery.Capacity[i] == battery_capacity

    # def _p_balance(battery, i):
    #     return battery.discharge_power_fcr[i] <= 0 | battery.charge_power_fcr[i] <= 0

    # Set constraint and objective for the battery
    battery.capacity_constraint = Constraint(battery.Period, rule=capacity_constraint)
    battery.over_charge = Constraint(battery.Period, rule=over_charge)
    battery.over_discharge = Constraint(battery.Period, rule=over_discharge)
    battery.negative_discharge = Constraint(battery.Period, rule=negative_discharge_spot)
    battery.objective = Objective(rule=maximise_profit, sense=maximize)
    # battery._p_balance = Constraint(battery.Period, rule=_p_balance)

    # Maximise the objective
    opt.solve(battery, tee=False)
```

If you look at the results, you can see that in the 'FCR' market it is simultanously charging and discharging.

[image: Optimal dispatch]

**I have tried:**

Naive approach. Supply an OR-condition:
def _p_balance(battery, i):
return battery.discharge_power_fcr[i] == 0 | battery.charge_power_fcr[i] == 0

Multiplying:
def _p_balance(battery, i):
return battery.discharge_power_fcr[i] * battery.charge_power_fcr[i] == 0

-> This make the problem non-linear, which is not supported by GLPK.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a full answer, but too long for a comment.

You don't really have a model for "the battery" here.  You have a market model for 4 energy markets, I think.

You don't have much in explanatory comments in your code, but I think you have 4 markets:  IntraDay, Day Ahead, FCR, AFRR that each have a price and cost associated with them.  So you are effectively modeling a distribution system, and it would be totally legit if there was some price disparity to produce the output you show.  If FCR cost is low, and price is high (in the FCR market and others), you could buy a massive quantity and sell it in the same market or the others, which appears to be happening.

So, if we look at your objective function, esp. the FCR part in isolation, it appears you are using the same cost value as a multiplier for both cost & rev.  The only difference is EFFICIENCY.  ...And your EFFICIENCY is set to 1, so the cost is neutral for whatever you do in FCR market, so the solution the solver provides may have both charge and discharge...  the OBJ value will be neutral to this.  So, try changing your efficiency to something slightly < 1 and I think you will see (partial) improvement.

also a nits:  You have `Capacity[i]` as a variable.  Typically "capacity" is a *fixed* value, like 10MJ.  I'd rename it "charge" or "state"

You shouldn't have to constrain discharge when price is negative... the OBJ should handle that for you and I think the change in efficiency will negate that constraint.