# scipy.optimize.minimize SLSQP indirect constraints problem

Tags: python, linear-programming, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am struggling with `minimize` (`method=SLSQL`) and need help. This is a simplified car battery (dis)charging problem to prop up the power grid during reduced stability (peak demand). What I expect to happen is that during such instability, the battery gets discharged as much as possible when the price of electricity is highest and charged when the price is lowest, and the grid is stable again. Instead, the optimization happily says it succeeded but either didn't optimize anything or ignores one or more constraints. I played around with the parameters passed to SLSQP, and when I set `esp=1`, things start happening, but it never comes close to discharging the battery completely, and does not attempt to recharge (much). It can happen, that it discharges the battery beyond zero to -2 or so.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511284/scipy-optimize-minimize-method-slsqp-ignores-constraint) someone suggested using transformations to enforce variable limits, but in this case, it's an indirect constraint applied to the combination of several variables. Are transforms still an option?

The constraint that the battery should be recharged to 1 at the end of the cycle is ignored, too.

I imagine SLSQP is not the best search algorithm for this, and I would be thankful for suggestions for better options for the long term. Even telling me what kind of problem (in optimization terms) this is would be very much appreciated.  Short term, I would be very thankful to point out how I can get SLSQP to work.

UPDATE: Someone told me that this might be a linear programming problem. How does that work with such flexible price data if that is the case? Where can I find an example explaining how to tackle it?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, OptimizeResult
from typing import TypedDict

SOC_MAX = 1.0  # normalized
ONE_MINUTE= 60
CHARGING_SOC_PER_SEC = SOC_MAX / (3*60*60)  # fully charge in 3h
CHARGE_TIME_MAX_SECONDS = 3*60*60 # in seconds


time_a = np.arange(171901, step=900)    
price_a = np.array([
       143.08, 143.08, 143.08, 140.25, 140.25, 140.25, 140.25, 130.84,
       130.84, 130.84, 130.84, 130.03, 130.03, 130.03, 130.03, 138.7 ,
       138.7 , 138.7 , 138.7 , 169.95, 169.95, 169.95, 169.95, 204.37,
       204.37, 204.37, 204.37, 230.09, 230.09, 230.09, 230.09, 219.09,
       219.09, 219.09, 219.09, 207.62, 207.62, 207.62, 207.62, 213.26,
       213.26, 213.26, 213.26, 206.2 , 206.2 , 206.2 , 206.2 , 211.11,
       211.11, 211.11, 211.11, 215.9 , 215.9 , 215.9 , 215.9 , 227.28,
       227.28, 227.28, 227.28, 234.97, 234.97, 234.97, 234.97, 257.99,
       257.99, 257.99, 257.99, 274.33, 274.33, 274.33, 274.33, 236.  ,
       236.  , 236.  , 236.  , 202.95, 202.95, 202.95, 202.95, 183.63,
       183.63, 183.63, 183.63, 165.92, 165.92, 165.92, 165.92, 145.07,
       145.07, 145.07, 145.07, 165.39, 165.39, 165.39, 165.39, 152.51,
       152.51, 152.51, 152.51, 145.87, 145.87, 145.87, 145.87, 143.06,
       143.06, 143.06, 143.06, 145.38, 145.38, 145.38, 145.38, 159.61,
       159.61, 159.61, 159.61, 183.77, 183.77, 183.77, 183.77, 210.8 ,
       210.8 , 210.8 , 210.8 , 213.77, 213.77, 213.77, 213.77, 203.33,
       203.33, 203.33, 203.33, 200.97, 200.97, 200.97, 200.97, 199.02,
       199.02, 199.02, 199.02, 193.72, 193.72, 193.72, 193.72, 179.7 ,
       179.7 , 179.7 , 179.7 , 165.57, 165.57, 165.57, 165.57, 163.94,
       163.94, 163.94, 163.94, 178.01, 178.01, 178.01, 178.01, 200.93,
       200.93, 200.93, 200.93, 201.01, 201.01, 201.01, 201.01, 193.47,
       193.47, 193.47, 193.47, 165.32, 165.32, 165.32, 165.32, 135.09,
       135.09, 135.09, 135.09, 125.56, 125.56, 125.56, 125.56, 104.86,
       104.86, 104.86, 104.86, 109.41, 109.41, 109.41, 109.41, 111.09])

stability_ranges = np.array([[ 33,  53],
       [ 71, 119],
       [131, 191]])
instability_ranges = np.array([[ 21,  32],
       [ 54,  70],
       [120, 130]])

booking_dt = np.dtype([("start", int),
                       ("duration", int),
                       ("soc", float),  # state of charge of the battery
                       ("delta_soc", float),  # change in battery charge
                       ("price", float)])  # this is what the user is billed.

class OptimisationItem(TypedDict, total=False):
    start: int # this might be not needed, as its the key in the dict
    duration: int
    soc: float  # state of charge of the battery
    delta_soc: float  # change in battery charge
    price: float # this is what the user is billed.
    bound_high: int
    bound_low: int


def integrate(start, duration):
    x_start = start
    x_end = start + duration
    x_data = np.linspace(x_start, x_end, 10)
    y_interp = np.interp(x_data, time_a, price_a)
    area = np.trapz(y_interp, x_data)
    return area


"""the battery can not be charged more than 100% and not less than 0%"""
def soc_constraint(x):
    soc = SOC_MAX
    durations = x[1::2]
    for i, j in durations.reshape(-1, 2):
        soc -= i * CHARGING_SOC_PER_SEC
        if soc < 0:
            break
        soc += j * CHARGING_SOC_PER_SEC
        if soc > SOC_MAX:
            soc = SOC_MAX - soc
            break
    return soc

"""the (dis)charging should happen only within the bounds"""
def bounds_constraint(x, bounds):
    end_points= bounds - (x[::2] + x[1::2])
    smallest_end_point = np.min(end_points)
    return smallest_end_point

"""the battery should be fully charge at the end of the cycle"""
def end_constraint(x, plan):
    final_soc_gap = x[-1] * CHARGING_SOC_PER_SEC - (SOC_MAX - plan["soc"][- 1])
    return final_soc_gap

def objective_func(x: np.array, plan) -> float:
    events= x.reshape(-1, 2)

    # insert the optimizsation variables into the plan
    plan["start"] = events[:,0]
    plan["duration"] = events[:,1]

    # start values for soc=SOC_MAX and delta_soc: 0
    plan["soc"][-1] = SOC_MAX
    plan["delta_soc"][-1] = 0
    plan["duration"][-1] = 0

    # straighten out the plan, calculate price and soc
    for step in range(len(plan)):
        plan["soc"][step] = plan["soc"][step - 1] + plan["delta_soc"][step - 1]
        if  step % 2 == 0:
            plan["delta_soc"][step] = - plan["duration"][step] * CHARGING_SOC_PER_SEC
            plan["price"][step] = - integrate(plan["start"][step], plan["duration"][step])
        else:
            plan["delta_soc"][step] = plan["duration"][step] * CHARGING_SOC_PER_SEC
            plan["price"][step] = + integrate(plan["start"][step], plan["duration"][step])

    price: float = plan["price"].sum()
    return price

def optimise_discharge_plan(plan: np.array, discharge_events_d) -> np.array:
    x_initial = []
    bounds = []
    constraints = []
    bounds_high_l = []
    for time in plan["start"]:
        data_set = discharge_events_d[time]
        x_initial.append(time)
        x_initial.append(data_set["duration"])
        bound_low = data_set["bound_low"]
        bound_high = data_set["bound_high"]
        bounds_high_l.append(bound_high)
        bounds.append((bound_low, bound_high))
        bounds.append( (0, min(CHARGE_TIME_MAX_SECONDS, bound_high - bound_low)))
    bounds_high = np.array(bounds_high_l)
    constraints.append({"type": "ineq", "fun": bounds_constraint, "args": (bounds_high,)})
    constraints.append({"type": "eq", "fun": end_constraint, "args": (plan,)})
    constraints.append({"type": "ineq", "fun": soc_constraint})


    result:OptimizeResult = minimize(objective_func, np.array(x_initial),
                                     args=plan,
                                     method="SLSQP",
                                     bounds=bounds,
                                     constraints=constraints,
                                     #options={"eps": 1 , "maxiter": 1000, "ftol": 1.0, "disp": True},
                                     )
    print(result.x.reshape(-1, 4),"\n", result, "\n",plan)


def main():

    discharge_events_l:list[booking_dt] = []
    discharge_events_d: dict = {}
    for range_cnt, (instability_range, stability_range) in enumerate(zip(instability_ranges, stability_ranges)):
    # build up list of discharge times, that we can modify in the optimisation step
        if instability_range[0] == instability_range[1]:
            time_max_price = instability_range[0]
        else:
            max_index = np.argmax(price_a[instability_range[0]:instability_range[1]])
            time_max_price = time_a[instability_range[0] + max_index]
        instability_item: OptimisationItem = {"bound_low": time_a[instability_range[0]],
                                              "bound_high": time_a[instability_range[1]]+15*60 -1,
                                              "duration": ONE_MINUTE, #  inital value
                                              "start": time_max_price,}
        discharge_events_d[time_max_price] = instability_item

        if stability_range[0] == stability_range[1]:
            time_min_price = stability_range[0]
        else:
            min_index = np.argmin(price_a[stability_range[0]:stability_range[1]])
            time_min_price = time_a[stability_range[0] + min_index]

        stability_item: OptimisationItem = {"bound_low": time_a[stability_range[0]],
                                            "bound_high": time_a[stability_range[1]]+15*60 -1,
                                            "duration": ONE_MINUTE,
                                            "start": time_min_price,}
        discharge_events_d[time_min_price] = stability_item

        event: booking_dt = np.zeros(2, dtype=booking_dt)
        # discharge
        event["start"][0] = time_max_price
        event["duration"][0] = ONE_MINUTE
        # charge
        event["start"][1] = time_min_price
        event["duration"][1] = ONE_MINUTE
        discharge_events_l.append(event)

    discharge_plan = np.array(discharge_events_l, dtype=booking_dt).reshape(-1)
    optimise_discharge_plan(discharge_plan, discharge_events_d)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This is not very easy to read. I would suggest first writing down the mathematical model. That makes it easier to reason about the model. Look at papers on this subject and you see how models are communicated.

Comment: I din't plow into the deets in your code... as noted it is a little tough to digest...  But a time-sequenced storage model can usually be cast as a MILP (Mixed Integer Linear Program) in some form.  I've answered a few similar questions on this site that might give you some ideas if you want to shift gears.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71453375/pyomo-optimisation-not-working-gas-plant-dispatch/71490094#71490094
, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71494297/python-pulp-linear-optimisation-for-off-grid-pv-and-battery-system/71501812#71501812 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73950740/add-a-constraint-to-prevent-simultanous-charing-and-discharging-of-a-battery/73951612#73951612

Comment: @erwin-kalvelagen, what makes it hard to read? I did describe the problem https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GhxNWpPU_OhQD5GD7-ihZEmCbofPyIH11PDRAeXF5lA/edit 
Would it help to add that to the initial text?

Comment: I am unsure how to turn my problem desciption into a mathematical model in terms of equations and constraints for a linear programming model. Is there a tutorial you could recommend that is similar to my problem?

Comment: I can only second Erwin's comment. That said, your main problem is the fact that your functions are not continuously differentiable (soc_constraint and bound_constraints) and thus violate the mathematical assumptions of the SLSQP algorithm. The best approach is probably reformulating your problem as MILP, as AirSquid suggested. You can ask at [OR.se](https://or.stackexchange.com) if you need further help regarding the reformulation. But I'd recommend to post a mathematical model over there as not many people are willing to read that much of code :P.

Comment: @joni Tomorrow, I will meet someone from my university willing to help me with this. To prepare well, I would like to come up with my best attempt at that mathematical model. Can you please point me to a (simple) guide on formulating such a model? Resources in German are welcome, too. Is the expression in the first sub-section here https://de.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/mixed-integer-linear-programming-algorithms.html such a mathematical model?

Answer (score 0):

One minor issue why the SLSQP algorithm failed was that it was too greedy and didn't want to buy/charge the battery. I introduced a medium reference against which the algorithm buys and sells, which got it to work a little better. I also made the price curve less step-like and more differentiable to make gradient descent easier.

However, it still does not optimize well at all. [image: Here] is a recent plot where the constraints get violated.